# How to find the type_info symbol without using /export (for unit tests)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, symbols, msvcrt, seh

**Context:**

We've implemented SEH/C++ exception handing in LLVM some time ago, to make our JIT'ted code compatible with native exceptions. As part of the exception handling code generation, internal information about type_info is necessary, because it's used in the exception handling tables. (More specifically, it's used in the RTTI TypeDescriptor)

In normal applications, type_info is internally added by the Microsoft linker to executables. However, the symbol is hidden by default. To expose it, you can use `/EXPORT:??_7type_info@@6B@` in the linker, which basically exposes the symbol so that we can use it for our bidding.

**Problem:**

In standard executables, this approach works just fine. However, we're also using the Microsoft Unit Test framework, which generates a DLL. Herein lies the problem, because the MS test runner (exe) isn't compiled with the '/EXPORT' flag above.

The result is that once the unit test is invoked, it generates an error (Symbol not found).

**Question:**

In short, we're looking for a solution that allows us to run our unit tests from within the MS test runner.

We've tried to lookup the symbol manually, so far without results.

Comment: Pretty hard to guess why you would care about the test runner .exe file at all.  The linker has nothing to do with that .exe file, the linking job was already done.  If you *need* it for the .exe then stop, it ain't going to happen.  Getting the symbol for the DLL that you are actually testing involves simply changing the linker settings for that DLL.  A very easy way to do this is to embed the linker instruction in the source code.  Something that you can squirrel away in a .h file for example.  Use `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:??_7type_info@@6B@")`

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry for the late reaction, we needed time to tinker with it based on your comment. No, we don't need it in the exe file, but symbols are resolved at runtime using the windows API calls, so they need to be exposed at runtime (from the DLL). That's what the export takes care of. Regardless, it appears as though you brought us on the right track; some minimal tests appear to be working currently so we'll get there. Thanks; I'd happily award the bounty.